# How to debug gstreamer pipeline with leaking file descriptors after gst_object_unref()?

Tags: debugging, gstreamer, file-descriptor, lsof, gstreamer-1.0

I have a custom pipeline that looks roughly like this in gstreamer shorthand:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://<url-for-stream> ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! imxvpudec ! *any-sink*
```

- any-sink doesn't matter, could be fakesink, imxipusink, or whatever (I'm on imx6 platform using freescale imx plugins). I can output to whichever sink I want and the issue is the same.

This type of pipeline works fine in gst-launch-1.0 because it doesn't need to clean itself up properly, but I need to use it inside my C++ application using direct GST API. This means I use `myPipeline = gst_pipeline_new("custom-pipeline")`, then allocate each plugin by name, link them, and run the pipeline. I later have a requirement to stop the pipeline and call `gst_object_unref(myPipeline)`. When doing this, I observe file descriptors being left behind. I later need to start the pipeline all over again, and so the leak is compounding. This needs to happen often enough that the leaking descriptors give me an exception:

`GLib-ERROR **: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Too many open files`

I can profile the open files with `lsof`...

```
lsof +E -aUc myGstApplication        
lsof: netlink UNIX socket msg peer info error
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
myGstApplication 5943 root    3u  unix 0xabfb6c00      0t0 11200335 type=STREAM
myGstApplication 5943 root   11u  unix 0xd9d47180      0t0 11207020 type=STREAM
```

... many more, depending on how long it runs...

```
myGstApplication 5943 root   50u  unix 0xabe99080      0t0 11211987 type=STREAM
```

I appear to get two new 'type=STREAM' file descriptors each time i unref() and rebuild the pipeline.

This is all fine and dandy to see the descriptors in lsof, but I don't know how to track down where these files are coming from in the code. Does any of the lsof output actually lead me to better debug information, for instance? . How do I track down where these leaks are really coming from and stop them? There has be be a better way... right?

I suspect `rtspsrc` gstreamer pipeline element is having something to do with this, but rtspsrc is itself a morass of underlying gstreamer implementation (udpsrcs, demuxers, etc, etc.) I'm not convinced that it's a bug within rtspsrc, because so many other people appear to use this one without reproducing the same thing. Could I be doing something in my application code that can bring about this behavior in a non-obvious way?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the `GST_DEBUG` option, that provides debug related info for each element in the pipeline.

Comment: Yes, the only thing I see there is this: `0:00:57.383872340  6101 0x69b34fb0 WARN                GST_PADS gstpad.c:3990:gst_pad_peer_query:<recv_rtp_sink_1:proxypad36> could not send sticky events
0:00:57.389069340  6101 0x69b34830 WARN                GST_PADS gstpad.c:3990:gst_pad_peer_query:<udpsrc14:src> could not send sticky events`

Comment: Had exactly same case. Mine was caused by not removing bus watch when freeing pipeline - remeber to do `gst_bus_remove_watch`  if you do `gst_bus_add_watch` before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well researched & interesting question!

According to the lsof output, the leaking file descriptors seem to originate from socketpair syscalls.  You confirm this with strace:

> strace -fe socketpair myGstApplication

After this, you could leave out filtering for the socketpair sycall, and look through the full strace output, trying to understand what these FDs are used for.  I tried this with gst-launch-1.0, with inconclusive results.  These FDs seem to be set readonly on both ends and nothing is ever transferred... so they must be used for control/coordination between several threads/subprocesses of the same application only.

Next try would be gdb:

> gdb -ex 'break socketpair' -ex run myGstApplication

When it halts at the breakpoint, look at the stacktrace with the *bt* command.  Probably installing the debug packages of gstreamer is a good idea to get more readable stacktraces.

HTH :)

Comment: Thanks micha -- I was already starting to play with strace, but you've given me more context to play around with. Will follow up again!

Comment: I've identified a gst func that calls socketpair which is leaking. the call `gst_poll_new_timer()` seems to be the one creating the socketpair as shown in GDB, but i haven't been successful at getting a stack trace:

Thread 1 hit Breakpoint 1, 0x6b07b0bc in gst_poll_new_timer ()
   from target:/usr/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x6b07b0bc in gst_poll_new_timer () from target:/usr/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0
#1  0x6b096960 in ?? () from target:/usr/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

 ...with debug packages AFAIK

Comment: scratch my previous comment - I need to reconfigure my gdb environment based on playing ball with 'yocto', because without doing it their way, I think I'm getting bad information. Still working toward those readible stack traces... it's a terrible pain

Comment: Just one more update for posterity - this method worked well enough for me to track down the root of the problem -- usage of `gst_element_get_bus(my_pipeline)` was not correctly decremented in reference counting mechanism. Tearing down the pipeline, I also had to refine the code to decrement the bus reference when creating a new pipeline via `gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(m_bus))`

Comment: hi @adowdy, I'm having a similar issue... could you post a little more detail on the code changes you had to make?  it would help me a lot.  thanks!